# Last download of a blob in a gcs bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Everything is in the question, is it possible to get the last download date of an blob in a gcs bucket. I know you can get the creation date, the last time the object was updated but could not get insight on the last download/access date.
Cheers

Comment: I've never done it, but have you had a look at the usage/audit logs? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Comment: You have to activate the audit logs (be careful, it will generate a lot of logs and start to cost if you have a huge activity on your buckets. You can mitigate that with a log router to keep only the relevant logs). And then to sink the logs in BigQuery. From there, you will be able to query BigQuery and to find your information. nothing out of the box.

Comment: Is your bucket configured for anonymous or authenticated access?